# Unexpected behavior of a site when scraping - requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a website from the Brazilian's government. (http://www.tesouro.gov.br/resultados-dos-leiloes)

The information I want to get is just the table below with, that contains 'Comunicados', 'Resultados da Semana' and the following links.

[image: The table I want to scrape]

My issue is that this site behaves differently from all that I've been working on.

Normally, the information is on the elements part, so I can scrape it directly with requests, or, in more complex sites, I should look for the API on Network and XHR part from the Chrome Inspect.

None of this has been working for me in this case.

Does anyone know how can I get this table? I think it might be simple (I hope so!lol)

I don't think this is going to help, as my code didn't work at all, but here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = "http://www.tesouro.gov.br/resultados-dos-leiloes"

data = requests.get(url)
bsobj = bs(data.content, "lxml") #just a small part of the site is shown.
```

ps: MacOS High Sierra / Python 3.6 - Working on Jupyter Lab

Comment: The data you are trying to grab are generated dynamically, moreover they are within an iframe. If you still want to get the data with your usual approach then try [this link](http://sisweb.tesouro.gov.br/apex/f?p=2501:6::::::).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this table is loaded with JavaScript that why requests do not work.
you need to use something like [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to extract the information:

example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.tesouro.gov.br/resultados-dos-leiloes")
bsobj = bs(driver.page_source, "lxml")

driver.close()
```

ps.
you could use also a headless browser driver like [phantomJS](https://pythonspot.com/selenium-phantomjs/)

After looking at the html of this site, i saw they were using iFrame to load this data, meaning that selenium won't work unless you give it the iframe source url.

So all you need is that iframe source url and you can get that data with requests as well

```
import requests

res = requests.get('http://sisweb.tesouro.gov.br/apex/f?p=2501:6')
bsobj = bs(res.content, "lxml")
print(bsobj)
```

Comment: Humm... I was wondering that. Do you know if Selenium works with external machine such as Heroku and Digital Ocean? I was trying to build and remotely scrap to monitor this website.

Comment: @CristianFavaroCarriço yes, it should work everywhere. headless servers will require you to install a virtual x server like xvfb to be able to run selenium

Comment: this virtual x server you mean the phantomJS? (you have no idea how useful is you help. I was totally lost)

Comment: @CristianFavaroCarriço if you use phantomJS you don't need virtual x server, if you use firefox or chorme driver then you do

Comment: @CristianFavaroCarriço i will try tomorrow, and will update my answer if needed